# Why Task.WhoId is not working?

Tags: apex

I believe we can edit WhoId in Task earlier. But now seems we can not and giving error like *Field is not writeable: Task.Who*. So, It means we can not assign any value to WhoId in task while creating it. Is it?

Any other solution if Yes..!

Thanks.

Below code will help for understand.

```java
Trigger Testexample on Contact (after insert) {

    List<Contact> retirveCons = [Select Id,Name,OwnerId from Contact where Id IN: Trigger.newmap.keyset()];

    List<Task> listTask = new List<task>();
    for(Contact con : retirveCons) {
        if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
            task ts = new Task();
            ts.Subject = 'Follow up with customer';
            ts.Who = con.Id;
            ts.OwnerId = con.OwnerId;
            listTask.add(ts);
        }
    }
    insert listTask;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippet? What are you trying to enter in WhoId?

Comment: @NagendraSingh: Just updated. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Who` to `WhoId`.

`Who` is the SobjectType lookup. So your code should not use that as you are passing `con.Id` which is a `Id`

Please use `WhoId` instead of `Who`

```
for(Contact con : retirveCons) {
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
        task ts = new Task();
        ts.Subject = 'Follow up with customer';
        ts.WhoId = con.Id;
        ts.OwnerId = con.OwnerId;
        listTask.add(ts);
    }
}
```

Comment: small observations will always work. Thanks Mr. Nagendra.